# entire php array save as string

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Is there a way to make the whole array content and make it a string so that i can save it. the string i want to save is same with the output of print_r( $Array ) function.

```
Array ( 
    [0982385099] => Array ( 
         [Title] => The Key of Life; A Metaphysical Investigation
         [ISBN] => 0982385099 
         [Author] => Randolph J. Rogers 
         [SalesRank] => 522631 ...
```

I'dd like to have that kind of string saved on a different file( a txt or php file) which will be made by the program that I'm doing.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
$str = var_export($array, true);
```

Answer (score 4):

Passing `true` as second parameter to the function [**print_r**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) will allow you to capture the output of `print_r`.

```
$str = print_r($arr, true);
```

Answer (score 4):

I would use [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php). That is because every browser can [parse it](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/).

code:

```
<?php

$ar = array(
    "1" => "Hello world!",
    "2" => 2
);

echo json_encode($ar);
```

output:

```
{"1":"Hello world!","2":2}
```

Answer (score 4):

Well you can use serialise() function to convert an array into string.

```
e.g. we have an array $arr
$arr = Array(
    "0" => "Dipendra",
    "1" => "Kshitiz",
    "2" => "Kushal",
    "3" => "Nirmal",
    "4" => "Prabin",
    "5" => "Prakash",
    "6" => "Sujit"
);

echo serialise($arr);

Now if we use serialise() function for this array we can view  the following output

a:7:{i:0;s:8:"Dipendra";i:1;s:7:"Kshitiz";i:2;s:6:"Kushal";i:3;s:6:"Nirmal";i:4;s:6:"Prabin";i:5;s:7:"Prakash";i:6;s:5:"Sujit";}
```

Thus we can use the array as a string.

Comment: The same way you can implement serialize() function for multidimensional array

Answer (score 0):

Your Database Table Structure Collation (*php_my_admin*) should also be defined accordingly as the default Latin **latin1_swedish_ci** didn't work for me. 
I used **utf8_bin**